# JavaScript retrieving size of specific ul

Tags: javascript

i have multiple ul's with their respective li's and i'm trying to retrieve the childNodes length of specific ul. My logic here was, retrieve them by tag, give them classes(so i can style them) so they get stored in an array and then i would just retrieve the li's as childNodes.length of that specific ul. However, when i tried to target those li i found out that it's actually retrieving ALL of the li's, regardless of ul.

Where did i go wrong?

```
  var parinte = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            var copil = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

            for (var x = 0; x < parinte.length; x++){
                parinte[x].setAttribute("class","parinte");
                for (y = 0; y <= parinte[x].childNodes.length; y++) {
                    copil[y].setAttribute("class","copil");
                }
            }


            var parinteClass = document.getElementsByClassName("parinte");
            var copilClass = document.getElementsByClassName("copil");
            var bottom = 0;
            var altBottom = -20;

            for (var x = 0; x < parinte.length; x++) {
                    parinteClass[x].style.position = "absolute";
                    parinteClass[x].style.bottom = bottom + "px";
                    bottom = bottom - 80;
                    for ( var y = 0; y <= parinte[x].childNodes.length; y++){
                        if (altBottom === -60) {
                            altBottom = -20;
                        }
                        copilClass[y].style.position = "absolute";
                        copilClass[y].style.bottom = altBottom + "px";
                        altBottom = altBottom - 20;

                     }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line

```
var copil = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

with

```
var copil = parinte.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

or

```
var copil = parinte.children;
```

Since you need to narrow your search inside that `ul` not in the entire `document`.

Your code should become now

```
        var parinte = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

        for (var x = 0; x < parinte.length; x++){
            parinte[x].setAttribute("class","parinte");
            var copil = parinte[x].getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (y = 0; y < copil.length; y++) {
                copil[y].setAttribute("class","copil");
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to break my code though, but i'l work around it.

Comment: It is breaking your code since parinte returned a list and I pasted a code (to give an idea) to use `getElementsByTagName` on it.  Try the code I have shared below that now/

Comment: sorry, first comment was posted before i saw your other code, yes it works now, thank you ! will mark for best answer after the minutes pass.

Comment: @BlazeBlue No probs, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

in line two replace

```
var copil = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

with

```
var copil = parinte.getElementsByTagName("li");
```